# Facebook Graph APIでWEBページのURLをUserIdやGroupIdに変換したい。

Tags: facebook, ajax, facebook-graph-api, facebook-api, facebook-php-sdk

下記のサイトの様にFacebookのURLをUserIdやGroupIdに変換したいのですが

http://lookup-id.com/

Facebook Graph APIには相当する物が見当たりません。
どうやって変換しているかお分かりになられる方はいませんでしょうか？

以前はこの方法で動作していたのですが

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030282/get-facebook-group-id-using-identifier-or-url

何故か、戻り値のJSONがブランクデーターになってしまって使えなくなりました。

ex.
{  "data": [  ]　}

Answer (score 1):

自己レスです。

Facebook Graph APIの search で jsonデータが取得出来るようになっているようです。
facebook側の不具合だったのかもしれません。

ですが　search　での変換はスマートでないような気もします。

ＵＲＬを変換できればいいのですが。私が知る限り、良い方法は無いようです。